# How Do I Embed Soundcloud Tracks Into Flipboard?

Tags: soundcloud, flipboard

The Flipboard site says that Soundcloud tracks can be embedded into RSS feeds, but there is no information on how to do this.
https://flipboard.com/rss/

For the past couple of days I've been in contact with one of Flipboard's support group who hasn't provided an answer.

Does anyone here know how to add Soundcloud tracks with an embed.

When I try to use YahooPipes to add the track embed codes, Pipes doesn't add the node.
http://pipes.yahoo.com/osliceplayspipes/soundcloudtest

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Pipes blocks  code, and (sadly) so does IFTT.

But, Yahoo Pipes doesn't block Wordpress Oembed code; so, it's possible to use IFTT to turn the RSS into blog posts, and then subscribe to that RSS in Flipboard, and it has the playable Soundcloud embeds.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<figure>
  <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/34019569&color=0066cc"></iframe>
</figure>
```

Comment: I just realized what's going on : Yahoo pipes completely ignores the iframe tag.

Is there a fix for that, or some other way I could edit the RSS to include that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171887/regex-with-iframe-in-yahoo-pipes?rq=1

Seem like pipes blocks <iframes> for safety. Sheesh.

Do you know of another semi-simple way for me to add an iframe?

Comment: Okay, I have figured out a work around :